# how does jvm enter in public static void main?

Tags: java, jvm

How can jvm enter in default class:

```
class try1
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ...
}
}
```

In it how does JVM access this method?

In packages, if a class is 'default' its public methods cant be accessed from outside the package, so how does jvm enter this class?

Comment: The JVM is what controls the visibility of methods. Also, `public static` is clearly `public`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch His point is that `try1` isn't `public`.

Comment: @Powerlord My point is the JVM is what interprets all the byte-codes (even the private ones).

Comment: It's not public, but it has package scope.  That is all that is needed.

Answer (score 10):

It is not JVM itself who invokes `main` method. This is rather a job of Java launcher, i.e. `java.exe`.
Java launcher is a small program written in C that uses regular [JNI functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html):

1. `JNI_CreateJavaVM` to create a new instance of JVM and to obtain an instance of `JNIEnv`;
2. `JNIEnv::FindClass` to locate the main class specified in the command line;
3. `JNIEnv::GetStaticMethodID` to find `public static void main(String[])` method in class #2.
4. `JNIEnv::CallStaticVoidMethod` to invoke the method found in #3.

In fact, JNI allows you to work with all classes, methods and fields, even with `private` modifier.

Comment: While all this is true, it's an implementation detail of a particular implementation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the JVM does not enter the method, it invokes (calls) it (yes, it matters). The keyword `public` declares that the method can be accessed from anywhere (different `packages`); the `static` keyword declares that you can call the method without instatiating the `class` (among other things) and as far as I know the class that contains the main method is always `public`.

Answer (score 0):

You explicitly told java what class to load on the command line or in a .jar's Manifest if you're running an executable jar.

The Java Specification [Chapter 12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1) goes briefly into what happens when the JVM starts up. (The JVM Specification [Chapter 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.2) covers it in more detail.)

In short:
`java try1` will load the `try1` class, then link, verify, resolve, and initialize it.

Once that's done, it will look for a main method that is `public`, `static`, and `void` that accepts an array of `String`s, then it will execute that method.

The JVM doesn't care that your class wasn't public.  As the first class loaded, it is the current compilation unit and initial [access control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6) is calculated from it.