# HelloWorld program to a JVM code

Tags: java, jvm

Let's consider the following piece of code:

```
package p;
public class Simple {

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("HELLO!\n");
   }
}
```

and JVM code for that ( `javap -c Simple.class`):

```
Compiled from "Simple.java"

public class p.Simple {
  public p.Simple();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #3                  // String HELLO!\n
       5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return
}
```

And I have a questions:

1. Probably, the entry point is the `main` function. But, before that, it is neccesary to invoke a constructor for Simple class.
   So, how does it work? I mean, who calls firstly the construactor and then pass a control to `main`?
   If I am wrong please explain me how the control flow works.
2. Instructions like `getstatic` take arguments like `#2` . What does it mean `#2`?
3. Comment looks like: `// Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V`
   What does it mean `V`?
4. How does the control flow work?

Comment: "But, before that, it is neccesary to invoke a constructor for Simple class." No, it is not. `main` is a __static__ method.

Comment: I see no constructor being *invoked*. Yes one is created by default for any class without an explicit constructor, but I don't see one being invoked anywhere in the code above.

Comment: Ok, so please explain me how the control flow works.

Comment: See [how does jvm enter in public static void main?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557989/how-does-jvm-enter-in-public-static-void-main/24558676#24558676)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Java compiler automatically generates a constructor when none is defined explicitly. In your example, it's not called at all. It's just that autogeneration policy.
2. It is a reference to the `PrintStream` property `out` on `System`. The Java compiler automatically converts import statements into fully qualified object declarations.
3. `V` means `void`
4. Probably something like this:

   1. Load the reference.
   2. Create an anonymous String object with that value.
   3. Push a stack frame into place that jumps to the `println` method's entry point with reference to #2 as the parameter.

What #2 means:

```
import java.util.List;

List x;
```

becomes simply this:

```
java.util.List x = new java.util.ArrayList();
```

when the compiler generates bytecode. `java.lang` is automatically imported.

Comment: So, what is `#X`? Does the compiler "scans" for constants/object declarations and put it in array indexed by #X? 

"The Java compiler automatically generates a constructor when none is defined explicitly. In your example, it's not called at all. It's just that autogeneration policy." Ok. If I defined my own constructor for Simple class, when it will be called?

Comment: @Gilgamesz `#X` is the index into the constant pool. See ["The class File Format"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html)

Comment: The example is misleading. The sole declaration `List x;` does not suddenly include the instantiation of `java.util.ArrayList` after compiling.

Answer (score 0):

1. Constructor is not called in this case because main() is static.
2. getstatic gets the value of System.out static field
3. V means void, that is main() return type is void

Comment: "getstatic gets the value of System.out static field"
Ok, But, where is it? Is the value a reference? 
"Constructor is not called in this case because main() is static."
Ok, that is true. main() is static so it cannot call constructor. Does it mean that constructor is not called at whole?