# How can I find out the class containing the main() method inside the OpenJDK JVM (Hotspot) code?

Tags: jvm, java, jvm-hotspot

In [`thread.cpp`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/tip/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.cpp) the method `Threads::create_vm` is defined which initializes the *main thread* and the *VM thread*. While I found this code location, I would like to know how the *main thread* knows which Java `main()` method to execute, i.e., in which class to look for, but I couldn't find that out.

As soon as possible after the VM creation (or even before), I would like to obtain the class name (and its package) of the class that contains the main method (and as a first step, just `printf` it). I thought about looking at the bottom-most entry in the stack frame of the *main thread*, yet the stack frame does not yet exist during `Threads::create_vm`. Can someone help me pointing me in the right direction?

**tl;dr:** I want to modify the OpenJDK source to print the class name of the class containing the Java `main()` method, how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When VM is created, it does not know what class/method will be executed in it. It is a job of a [*launcher*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24557989/how-does-jvm-enter-in-public-static-void-main/24558676#24558676) to invoke main Java method using one of [JNI functions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#CallStatic_type_Method_routines). BTW, this method does not necessarily need to be called `main`.

> I want to modify the OpenJDK source to print the class name of the
>   class containing the Java main() method, how to do this?

You probably want to modify Java launcher then. See [java.c](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/5ea88e09f465/src/share/bin/java.c#l477).

Comment: Whay launcher written in C or this is source code JVM?