# What code does JVM write to call the main function?

Tags: jvm

JVM has an inbuilt try and catch block and in catch block there is a pointer of "Throwable class". In try block what code does JVM write to form string array and to call the main and pass the formed string array?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24558676/3448419) will probably help.

Comment: what i mean is that main function will not get called automatically, just like other function gets called by writing some code so there will be some code which JVM writes to call main function and i want to know that code which JVM writes to call main()..

Comment: So the link above should answer your questoin.

Comment: no its not the answer which i except..

Comment: Then clarify your expectations from the answer (by editing the question).

Comment: [Here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk10/file/b09e56145e11/src/java.base/share/native/libjli/java.c#l388) is the exact function that launches Java `main` method.

Comment: cool that helps me alot :)