# Where is the entry point for hotspot in openjdk 8u?

Tags: java, launcher, jvm-hotspot

I found the entry point for hotspot in openjdk 7u is located in the package "/share/tools/launcher/",
but this package disappeared in openjdk 8u. Where is it? or where is the entry point for hotspot in openjdk 8u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HotSpot JVM (libjvm.so) and Java launcher (java executable) are two different components.

The sources of Java launcher are in `jdk` tree, not `hotspot`:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/8ec1d42a9bad/src/share/bin

For more information see

- [Totally Confused with java.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26025656/3448419)
- [how does jvm enter in public static void main?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24558676/3448419)